# Extra white space after h2 when inside list

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Major Edit:** Turns out my issue was not repeated exactly the same here.  My issue appears when using bootstrap, and is *not* fixed when using `margin:0px;`.  See the updated code for the persisting issue.

I am building an ordered list of text, and noticed a slight issue.  When I nest other elements inside of a `li` element, I get a good amount of extra white space between the individual elements that is not controlled by margin or padding.  Throwing a border onto these elements reveals that each of the nested elements does not control that white space (seemingly).

My question is how do I control the amount of extra white space?

Demo of this issue:

```css
#questionList li {
  font-size: 3em;
  margin-left: 3em;
}
#questionList li h2 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: 45px;
  margin:0px;
}
#questionList li small {
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: 14.72px;
  margin:0px;
}
#questionList li p {
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin:0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://bootswatch.com/paper/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <ol id="questionList" class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
      <li>
        <h2>Qg</h2>
        <small>sub header</small>
        <p>P1</p>
      </li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What makes you think it's not the margin causing the white space?

Comment: I did not think this issue was caused by bootstrap, so I omitted that part, but it turns out, if not useing bootstrap, the margin fixes it, but when bootstrap is used, it stays broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paragraphs and headers do indeed have default margin, as demonstrated below, if we set the margin for each equal to zero.

```css
ol li h2 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
ol li small {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
ol li p {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
h2,
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <h2>
      Header
    </h2>
    <small>
      Sub header
    </small>
    <p>
      paragraph of text
    </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2>
      Header2
    </h2>
    <small>
      Sub header2
    </small>
    <p>
      paragraph of text2
    </p>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: This is true, and fixes the issue if not using bootstrap.  See my update to the code for the persisting issue.

Comment: @Burn_E99 That's caused by `font-size: 3em`.

Comment: Is it?  If I drop that in here: http://jsfiddle.net/6pjoz5mc/1/ it works without bootstrap, but if you look at the new code and demo in my question, the issue persists, leading me to think it is bootstrap doing something.

Comment: @Burn_E99 Yes. https://jsfiddle.net/Hatchet/mcftv4tL/ See, the spacing is the same with or without the additional text. Removing `font-size: 3em;` from the `li` styles fixes the additional space.

Comment: Alright, I see that.  Is there a way that the spacing can be fixed with keeping the `font-size:3em;`?  I need the numbers in the `li` to be that size, so removing the `font-size` is not an option (unless if there is a way to keep the size but use a different css trick).

Comment: @Burn_E99 Not that I can think of, off the top of my head. You can change `line-height`, or implement custom list numbers, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/Hatchet/0wo8x1fq/1/

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed controlled by the margin on the individual elements.

Fiddle for example here: https://jsfiddle.net/25f3bcwr/

```
ol li h2 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin:0px;
}
ol li small {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin:0px;
}
ol li p {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because headers if not defined, by default they posses some default characteristics e.g their size, spacing, font-weight.

I believe, those are not **white spaces** White spaces are created using `&nbsp;`.

Try to use `display:inline-block;` or `display:inline;` and then ad break line  in the css style and then add break line code at the end of your sentence`<br>` see some difference

```css
 ol li h2 {
 border: 1px solid red;
 display: inline;
  
 }
 ol li small {
 border: 1px solid red;
 display: inline;
  
 }
 ol li p {
 border: 1px solid red;
 display: inline;
 }
```

```html
      <ol>
         <li>
             <h2>
             Header
             </h2><br>
     <small>
       Sub header
     </small><br>
              <p>
              paragraph of text
              </p>
     </li>
          <li>
              <h2>
              Header2
              </h2><br>
        <small>
          Sub header2
        </small><br>
             <p>
             paragraph of text2
             </p>
      </li>
    </ol>
```

Result [image]

Comment: This does not fix my issue completely.  It may get rid of the whitespace, but the `small` element is no longer below the `h2`.  Is there a way to move the `small` to the next line, but not have the excess whitespace.

Comment: @Burn_E99 Sorry for late reply, i have edited the code again What about that